# Advantage of breaking one API call into multiple API calls

Tags: performance, api, networking

I have an API call that takes 18s min to return a bunch of data. This data is an object which has multiple keys.

Is it ok and considered a better practice to break this up into multiple calls for each key separately?

Is sending one API call which takes long to return back better than sending multiple calls(5 min) for the network load and for server as well?

Answer (score 0):

Design first for an API with a simple interface, and if loading becomes an issue, then address that in the implementation.

An API call that breaks a single object into multiple sub-objects that must be re-assembled by the user would add complexity for the user of the API. This is **bad** from an API-design perspective.

If your testers discover that it becomes necessary to address network load, you could throttle back the transfer of the data in the implementation of that API call without changing the interface. For example:

- You could transfer each key, pausing briefly between keys to allow
  other network traffic to occur. This would be invisible to users of
  your API, although they might notice that this particular API call
  now runs slower.
- Or you could retrieve the keys from the server on an as-needed basis. That is, don't retrieve the key into the local copy of the object until it is requested via another API call. Again, this would be invisible from the perspective of the API users, though the initial load of each key would be slower (subsequent accesses to already-retrieved keys would of course be fast).

In both of these examples, it is necessary to add complexity to the overall design, but this complexity is hidden from the user of the API. This is key to good API design.